# How Do i use Wireshark to investigate which packets are being sent/received by which applications?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, wireshark

I've been given an assignment to track background data usage by my system using Wireshark. The problem is that I'm unable to figure out which applications are sending particular packets. Any help would be highly appreciated.[Here is a sample image of what I'm able to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw2Sb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each application is sending packets through a port. You can find out which application uses what port,  running the `netstat -b` command which will give you back a list of the connections and their associated executable.
Then you can go back to wireshark and apply a filter like `PPP.port == XXXX` where **PPP** is the protocol the application uses (either tcp or udp) and **XXXX** is the port number.

Comment: "_Each application is sending packets through a port._" That is simplistic because only those applications using one of the transport protocols that actually have ports (not all do, and not all applications will even use a transport protocol) as addresses will use ports.